# RegionPlot - not a valid region to plot

Tags: plotting, regions

I have two regions like this

```
reg1 = ImplicitRegion[(-5. + x)^2 + (-3. + y)^2 <= 0.25 || (0.386909 + x Tan[25 \[Degree]] 
<= y <= 5.61309 - x Tan[25 \[Degree]] && 0 <= x <= 5.), {x, y}];

reg2 = ImplicitRegion[(-5. + x)^2 + (-3. + y)^2 <= 0.49 || (0.166233 + x Tan[25 \[Degree]]
<= y <= 5.83377 - x Tan[25 \[Degree]] && 0 <= x <= 5.), {x, y}];

Show[RegionPlot[reg1, AspectRatio -> Automatic], RegionPlot[reg2, AspectRatio -> Automatic]]
```

[image]

I need to see and work with their difference

```
RegionPlot[RegionDifference[reg2,reg1], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

but it brings about an error

```
RegionPlot::invplotreg: {RegionDifference[ImplicitRegion[Plus[<<2>>]^2+Plus[<<2>>]^2<=0.49||(0.166233 +Times[<<2>>]<=y<=5.83377 +Times[<<3>>]&&0<=x<=5.),{x,y}],ImplicitRegion[Plus[<<2>>]^2+Plus[<<2>>]^2<=0.25||(0.386909 +Times[<<2>>]<=y<=5.61309 +Times[<<3>>]&&0<=x<=5.),{x,y}]]} is not a valid region to plot. >>
```

Comment: What are `w3` and `w2`? Maybe you meant `reg2` and `reg1`; in that case `RegionPlot[RegionDifference[reg2, reg1], AspectRatio -> Automatic]` works with no problems.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant reg2, reg1. But it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try quitting the kernel, maybe you have some old definitions.

Comment: works here too, maybe a version issue.

Comment: Works in version 11 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

```
RegionDifference @@ (DiscretizeRegion /@ {reg2, reg1})
```

[image]